# ¿Por qué al pasar una lista como parámetro de una funcion y modificarla, se modifica la lista original?

Tags: python, funciones, lista

Ejemplo:

```
def exampol(x, y):
    for i in x:
        x[i] = x[i]*x[i]
    for j in range(0, len(y)):
        y[j] = y[j]*y[j]
    return x, y

x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60]

exampol(x, y)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Después de llamar a la función `exampol()` la salida es:

```
x = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
y = [0, 100, 400, 900, 1600, 2500, 3600]
```

No entiendo por qué sucede esto. Hasta donde yo sé, las variables de una función son de ámbito local y no debería modificarse el valor original de los parámetros pasados a la función.

¿Por qué se modifican las variables originales pasadas como argumento a la función?

Comment: Sin embargo, si hago lo mismo con una variable que no sea una lista (por ejemplo `x = 4`, la variable original no es modificada.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Son dos conceptos diferentes, una cosa es el nombre o identificador (lo que llamamos "variable") y otra el objeto al que está asociado. Tu lista no es definida dentro de la función, se la pasas como argumento.

En Python **una variable es realmente solo un nombre, un identificador, que está asociado a la referencia de un objeto en memoria** y que nos sirve para acceder a él. Un mismo objeto puede tener diversos nombres asociados a él:

- Si hacemos:

  ```
  a = []
  b = a
  ```
- `a` y `b` son  nombres que están **asociados ambos al mismo objeto `list` en memoria**, podemos hacer que `a` se asocie a otro objeto reasignando:

  ```
   a = {"k": 4}
  ```
- Podemos usar `a` o cualquier otro nombre asociado al objeto para acceder a él, a sus métodos y atributos:

  ```
  a["v"] = 13
  ```

Una variable definida dentro de una función solo existe dentro de esa función tal y como comentas, además cualquier intento de reasignación a una variable global dentro de la función  causa la creación de una variable local del mismo nombre dejando intacta la global (siempre que no usemos `global` o `nonlocal`). Podemos decir que los identificadores globales dentro de una función son por defecto de solo lectura, esto se debe a que el intérprete primero busca la variable en el espacio de nombres local a al función, si no lo encuentra busca en el global.

Ahora bién, cualquier intento de cambiar el objeto  al que está asociada una variable global dentro de una función crea automáticamente una variable local del mismo nombre. Cuando digo "cambiar el objeto  al que está asociada" no me refiero a modificar las propiedades del objeto en sí, me refiere a hacer que la variable apunte a otro objeto, una asignación:

```
a = []       # Hacer que a apunte a un nuevo objeto (asignación)
a.append(4)  # a solo se usa para acceder al objeto y modificarlo.
```

**Los argumentos de funciones/métodos en Python son pasados por asignación, por "referencia a objeto"** (no se pasa el valor o una copia del objeto, simplemente se le pasa una referencia a un objeto en memoria).

Además del paso por referencia a objeto, es importante tener en cuenta el concepto de mutabilidad de los objetos (*ver lista al final de la respuesta). Las **listas son objetos mutables**, esto implica que las listas que modificas dentro de la función son los mismos objetos que los que le pasas como argumento:

- Si el objeto es inmutable, como un entero, un float o una cadena esto no pasa, porque "modificar" un objeto inmutable mediante una variable implica en realidad siempre crear un nuevo objeto y una asignación de la nueva referencia a la variable. Por lo tanto, en el momento que dentro de la función hacemos algo como `x += 1`, siendo `x` un entero pasado como argumento, el nombre `x` pasa a estar asociado a un nuevo objeto en memoria, ya que la secuencia es sumar uno a x, almacenarlo en un nuevo objeto entero y asociarlo (asignarlo) al nombre `x`:

  ```
  def foo(x):
      print("Id del argumento x antes de modificar: {}".format(id(x)))
      x += 1
      print("Id del argumento x después de modificar: {}".format(id(x)))

  n = 5
  print("Id de variable n: {}".format(id(n)))
  foo(n)
  ```

  Salida:

  ```
  Id de variable n: 140104186448160
  Id del argumento x antes de modificar: 140104186448160
  Id del argumento x después de modificar: 140104186448192
  ```
- Como una lista es un objeto mutable, al modificar sus valores dentro de la función no se crea un nuevo objeto, sino que es modificada directamente:

  ```
  def foo(x):
      print("Id del argumento x antes de modificar: {}".format(id(x)))
      x += [1]
      print("Id del argumento x después de modificar: {}".format(id(x)))

  l = [5]
  print("Id  de variable l: {}".format(id(l)))
  foo(l)
  print(l)
  ```

  **Salida:**

  ```
  Id de variable l: 139791555449480
  Id del argumento x antes de modificar: 139791555449480
  Id del argumento x después de modificar: 139791555449480
  [5, 1]
  ```

Si no quieres que esto ocurra debes pasar a la función una copia de la lista o crear la copia dentro de la propia función:

```
def exampol(x, y):
    x = x[:]        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    y = y[:]        # <<<<<<<<<<<<<

    for i in x:
        x[i] = x[i]*x[i]
    for j in range(0, len(y)):
        y[j] = y[j]*y[j]
    return x, y

x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60]

exampol(x, y)

print(x)
print(y)
```

En este caso se crea una copia mediante slicing, también puedes usar [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.copy). Si tu lista solo contiene enteros (inmutables) con esto es suficiente. Si tu lista tuviera elementos mutables, como listas o diccionarios, lo anterior solo crea una copia de la lista, pero sus elementos siguen siendo los mismos que los de la lista original (mismas referencias) por lo que debes usar [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deapcopy) para que los elementos que contiene también sean copiados.

---

**Objetos Pythón según su mutabilidad:**

Para completar la respuesta teniendo en cuenta el comentario de @fedorqui dejo una clasificación de los objetos en Python estándar según su mutabilidad:

- **Mutables:**

  - `bytearray`
  - `dict`
  - `list`
  - `set`
  - Clases definidas por el usuario (excepto que se indique lo contrario)
- **Inmutables:**

  - `bool`
  - `bytes`
  - `complex`
  - `decimal`
  - `int`
  - `float`
  - `frozenset`
  - `str`/`unicode`
  - `tuple`
  - `range`

Además de lo anterior, en la biblioteca estándar tenemos el módulo `collections` que proporciona alternativas a los contenedores preconstruidos y que normalmente son wrappers o se basan en los anteriores (y por tanto teniendo sus misma propiedad de inmutabilidad o no que estos).

Comment: Gran respuesta. Podría ser útil añadir un listado de cuáles son los tipos mutables y cuáles no. Si no voy equivocado, mutables son las listas, diccionarios y sets.

Comment: Creo que querías decir `deep_copy`. Excelente respuesta.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Además desconocía el tema de la mutabilidad. Creo que tienes una errata en el primer bloque de código. En el segundo  `print("Dirección de memoria de argumeto x antes ` creo que debería poner después.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo gracias por la observación, además de la falta ortográfica sobraba el underscore... :(. Corregido, al igual que el error comentado por Zhisi. Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón, puede ser útil ya que la mutabilidad es una de las causas de este comportamiento. He añadido una lista al final de la respuesta como anexo, creo que están todos los tipo/contenedores principales pero es posible que me falte alguno, si alguien se acuerda  de alguno más que no dude en comentar. Un saludo.