# Eliminar duplicados python

Tags: python, lista

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cuál debo simular un cartón de loteria.
Este está compuesto por 3 listas y debe devolver una lista de listas, el tema es que entre esas 3 listas no debe de haber duplicados, y ese es el problema que estoy teniendo
mi código es este:

```
import random
def cartonloteria():
    fila1=random.randint(1,99)
    fila2=random.randint(1,99)
    fila3=random.randint(1,99)
    listavacia=[]
    listavacia2=[]
    listavacia3=[]
    listavaciapre=[]
    listavaciapres=[]
    string=""
    listapre=[]
    for i in range(5):
        fila1=random.randint(1,99)
        fila2=random.randint(1,99)
        fila3=random.randint(1,99)
        if  fila1 not in listavacia and fila2 not in listavacia and fila3 not in listavacia:
            listavacia.append(fila1)
        if fila2 not in listavacia2 and fila1 not in listavacia2 and fila3 not in listavacia2:
                listavacia2.append(fila2)
        if fila3 not in listavacia3 and fila2 not in listavacia3 and fila1 not in listavacia3:
                    listavacia3.append(fila3)

        listapre=[listavacia3,listavacia2,listavacia]
    return listapre 
print(cartonloteria())
```

Quiero que en la `listapre`, no haya duplicados entre `listavacia3`, `listavacia2` y `listavacia`, (obviar algunas variables que no se usan, las cuales las creé solo para probar cosas)

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal si, sacrificando un poquito la memoria, mejor utilizas una lista consecutiva, pero desordenada al azar, y solo vas sacando cada número de ahí?

Obvio que este algoritmo se desaconseja para una lotería real (se debe usar algoritmos de generación aleatoria más potentes), pero para cuestiones académicas funciona.

```py
import random

def rand_generator(lim1, lim2):
    li = list(range(lim1, lim2+1))
    random.shuffle(li)
    for v in li:
        yield v

def cartonloteria(clist, cnums, lim1, lim2):
    listapre = list([] for _ in range(clist))
    get_random = rand_generator(lim1, lim2)
    for i in range(clist):
        for _ in range(cnums):
            listapre[i].append(next(get_random))
    return listapre
```

`rand_generator()` es un generador de lista aleatoria donde ningún elemento se repite, así que en `cartonloteria()` solo hay que ir pidiendole valores.

```py
# Uso: cartonloteria(cant_sublistas, cant_nums_x_subl, lim_inf, lim_sup)
print(cartonloteria(3, 5, 1, 99))
# [[65, 34, 86, 47, 29], [60, 90, 53, 22, 8], [26, 85, 82, 54, 14]]
print(cartonloteria(3, 3, 0, 9))
# [[1, 6, 8], [7, 2, 5], [9, 4, 0]]
```

---

[ EDIT ] Intentando arreglar el código que hiciste, la parte que tienes "más complicada" es que no sabes cuántos intentos tienes que hacer hasta que `random.randint()` genere un número no usado. Esto será así para cada sublista.
Para resolverlo, propongo que los valores que ya han sido usados se almacenen en otra lista llamada `lista_usados` y crear una función `generar_aleatorio()` que intentará infinitas veces obtener un número que NO esté en la *lista de usados*. Cuando encuentra un valor, lo agrega a la lista `usados` y lo devuelve.

```py
import random

def generar_aleatorio(usados):
    while True:
        valor = random.randint(1, 99)
        if valor not in usados:
            usados.append(valor)
            return valor

def cartonloteria():
    listavacia = []
    listavacia2 = []
    listavacia3 = []
    listapre = []
    
    lista_usados = []
    for i in range(5):
        listavacia.append(generar_aleatorio(lista_usados))
        listavacia2.append(generar_aleatorio(lista_usados))
        listavacia3.append(generar_aleatorio(lista_usados))
    listapre = [listavacia3, listavacia2, listavacia]
    return listapre
    
print(cartonloteria())
```

Posiblemente preguntes: ¿Cómo se actualiza `lista_usados`, si `usados` nunca se devuelve desde `generar_aleatorio`?. Esto es una propiedad de Python y otros lenguajes, que debes tener siempre en mente. Cuando se pasa una lista o diccionario a una función, todo lo que se haga sobre esa estructura se replica automáticamente en la estructura original.
[¿Por qué al pasar una lista como parámetro y modificarla, se modifica la lista original?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132735/80870)

Comment: me gustó tu respuesta, pero no hay alguna forma de hacer que no existan duplicados en la lista de mi solución?, ya que creo que haciendolo de forma manual voy a aprender bastante más

Comment: @JoseIgnacioLavecchia agregué una edición donde trato de mejorar el código que ya tenías.